# Combine list of lists with similar values in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of lists, like so:

```
items = [['118', 'white'], ['118','Jack'], ['118','guilty'],  ['200','black'], ['200','mark'], ['200','not guilty']]
```

Is there a way to use a for loop to grab the second value in each list and collapse it into a new list?

Like so:

```
['white', 'jack', 'guilty']
['black','mark','not guilty']
```

Comment: how did you decide where to break for the second list?

Comment: I need a new list for each unique "key". So all lists whose first value is the same get their own list.

Comment: @JonnyD List is always sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your list always has elements with the same key grouped as in your example, you can use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do this efficiently:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> items = [['118', 'white'], ['118','Jack'], ['118','guilty'],  ['200','black'], ['200','mark'], ['200','not guilty']]
>>> [[x[1] for x in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(items, lambda x: x[0])]
[['white', 'Jack', 'guilty'], ['black', 'mark', 'not guilty']]
```

You could also use [`operator.itemgetter(0)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as an alternative to `lambda x: x[0]`.

Note that if `items` does not necessarily have elements grouped by their keys, you can use `sorted(items)` instead of `items` in the `groupby()` call and it will work.

Here is a version that preserves the key as well:

```
>>> [(k, [x[1] for x in g]) for k, g in itertools.groupby(items, lambda x: x[0])]
[('118', ['white', 'Jack', 'guilty']), ('200', ['black', 'mark', 'not guilty'])]
```

You could pass this list directly into the `dict()` built-in function to convert this to a dictionary.

Comment: groupby is good BUT the caution here is that this assumes that they are sorted by key already.  If there is a '200' mixed into the '3 '118' values above, the grouping is not as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
entries = defaultdict(list)
for (key, value) in items:
    entries[key].append(value)
```

Now `entries` is a dict of lists of the second values. You can either get them by key ('118') or use `values()` for a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
output_dict = {}
for each_key in items:
  for each_item in each_key:
    try:
      output_dict[each_key].append(each_item) #fails as I'm trying to use a list as a dict key
    except Exception as e:
      output_dict[each_key] = [] #see above
      output_dict[each_key].append(each_item) #see above
for each_list in output_dict:
  print(each_list)
```

as [Peter DeGlopper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2337736/peter-deglopper) pointed out below, this code is bad and I should feel bad. I've commented the code to point out my error. There are better solutions, but just to correct my mistake:

```
items = [['118', 'white'], ['118','Jack'], ['118','guilty'],  ['200','black'], ['200','mark'], ['200','not guilty']]

output_dict = {}
for each_list in items:
  if each_list[0] not in output_dict: output_dict[each_list[0]] = list()
  output_dict[each_list[0]].append(each_list[1])

>>> for each_list in output_dict:
>>>  print(each_list)
['white','Jack','guilty']
['black','mark','not guilty']
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a mess. Let's start with the fact that `items` is a list of lists, and you can't use lists as dict keys, so `output_dict[each_key]` will always throw an exception. Even if it worked, you'd append both `'118'` and each word. And catching blanket exceptions like that is a bad practice. Sometimes it's faster to catch `KeyError` rather than use `if key in output_dict` or `output_dict.setdefault(key, [])`, but catching all `Exception` subclasses isn't safe.

Comment: Shoot, you're right. I was co-opting an old solution I floundered through for something slightly different where I had to take a grouping of objects of type `origin = [filename,size]` and reorder them as `filename = {'origin':size,...}` but I butchered the code along the way. Please disregard! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> k = set(x[0] for x in items)
>>> [ [x[1] for x in items if x[0] == key] for key in sorted(k) ]
[['white', 'Jack', 'guilty'], ['black', 'mark', 'not guilty']]
```